# WIndows option disappered in GRUB menu

Tags: linux, boot, debian, windows-11, grub

I recently set up a dual boot configuration with Windows 11 and Debian, and I've been using it without issues for a while. However, I've encountered a problem where the Windows 11 option has disappeared from the GRUB boot menu. I have already tried using 'sudo update-grub' with no success.
I'm looking for assistance to understand why this happened and how I can fix it to have the Windows option show up in the GRUB menu again.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5BwV.png]

Comment: Can you share the output of `efibootmgr` and `lsblk -f`? (Run them as root / with sudo if possible.) The output of `tree /boot/efi` (if the directory / mountpoint exists) could give us some insight as well. (Also, can you confirm whether os-prober is still installed?)

Comment: @TomYan here is a screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5BwV.png

Comment: Can you confirm that you can still boot to Windows by choosing it on the UEFI boot menu? (Or `sudo efibootmgr -n 0006` and reboot.) Any error/warning given by `update-grub`? Maybe try to reinstall os-prober, just in case.

Comment: @TomYan I tried `sudo efibootmgr -n 0006` and went into BIOS Flash update. After the grub doesnt show windows still. No error/warning given by `update-grub`.

Comment: Can you clarify? You mean the 0006 entry led you to some BIOS (UEFI) screen, or it booted to Windows and you also tried updating your UEFI? If it's the former, it could be that your Windows Boot Manager is somehow corrupted / gone (which is why I asked for `tree /boot/efi`). (But it could be that your UEFI is somewhat "broken" as well; so it's better to try your UEFI boot menu instead.) You should at least check whether `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` is still there.

Comment: @TomYan 006 entry led to BIOS Flash update. But anyway the issue is solved. I added `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false` to the `/etc/default/grub` and did 'update-grub'. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the help. The issue is resolved. Added `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false` to the `/etc/default/grub` file and did `update-grub`.

Comment: stack exchange tip: don´t type your reply into an answer form.  instead add a comment to another answer or to the original question.  Please cut out and delete this answer and paste it into an appropriate comment.

Comment: this is the valid answer, I don´t think it is a reply, it is the answer to the problem

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this video, you can add Windows entry manually in Grub file(/etc/grub.d/40_custom).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tyVRfVxiD08

```
menuentry "Windows" --class windows --class os {
    search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root $UUID
  chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

Replace $UUID with the output of `sudo blkid /dev/nvme0n1p1`